# how to separate documents from folders

Tags: document-set

I have a document library with 200 document sets. Each document sets have 5 to 10 files and records.
I must create a new document library and move only records and files into the new library.
Can you please help me with what my options would be?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you go to view settings, there is an option to see the documents without folders